# Openpyxl charts - data series from random unconnected cells possible?

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I'm currently experimenting with the python module openpyxl, trying to automate some tasks at work and generate spreadsheets automatically. For one of the required sheets I need to generate a scatter chart from tabulated data. However, the scatter chart should consist from multiple lines connecting two points each, so each of the individual x/y series in the scatter chart should connect two points only.

Generally I found from the openpyxl documentation that scatter charts are generated like in this small example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    [5, 30, 25],
    [6, 25, 35],
    [7, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Scatter Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Size'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Percentage'

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
for i in range(2, 4):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=7)
    series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")
```

However, the x (and y) coordinates of the two points I would like to connect in the scatter points are not located in adjacent cells.
So when I import the data series manually in excel by holding 'ctrl' and select two cells I get something like this:

'Sheet!$A$4;Sheet!$A$6'

instead of

'Sheet!$A$4:$A$6'

when dragging the cursor to select a range of cells.

For only two individual not-adjacent cells this means that I do not have a clear min_row/min_col/max_row etc.. but only a list of cell pairs (for both x and y). Is there a way create a data series in openpyxl as a list of cells instead of a connected/adjacent range?

Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no plans to support non-contiguous cell ranges in chart series. I would suggest you try and arrange your data or create references to it that will allow you to work with contiguous ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this doesn't work?
I've modified the example for a situation like yours and it seems to work for me:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size'],
    [2, 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [3, 40, 30],
    [4, 40, 25],
    [5, 50, 30],
    [6, 30, 25],
    [7, 25, 35],
    [None, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Scatter Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Size'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Percentage'

xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
for i in range(2, 4):
    values = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=2, max_row=8)
    series = Series(values, xvalues, title_from_data=True)
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of output spreadsheet]

Comment: the size header being on a different line than the batch headers is strange - the plot doesn't seem to match.